# Don't Average Column If Only One Value Exists

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to figure out how to include an `IF/ELSE` statement in my awk code says that if number of records equals one value, to not average, else average the column.

**nums Data File (with one value)**

```
57.43
```

**nums Data File (with multiple values)**

```
57.43
54.789
55.332
56.3278
```

**awk code:**

```
awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum/NR}' nums
```

Comment: But the average of one record is the same anyway. N/1 = N

Comment: If `nums` file only had one value, it would return that one value, else it would perform the vertical column average.

Comment: If you insist: `awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { if(NR>1) print sum/NR }'  nums`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this;

```
awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { if(NR>1) print sum/NR; else  print $0;}' nums
```